# Debugging css in Firebug

Tags: html, css, firebug

I'm having a problem finding out which css is actually applied to an element when using Firebug 1.11.2. I'm setting the paragraph font from my own css file (`d.css`), which is meant to over-ride 3 system css files (`a.css`, `b.css`, `c.css`).

1. I click on the html tab, and click on the `<p>` element that I'm
       trying to debug.
2. The style window on the right now shows the applied styles from `a.css`, `b.css`, and `c.css`, but not `d.css`. No paragraph font is shown, but I can change the paragraph `line-height`, for example, from `a.css`.
3. If I click on the `css` tab, and find `d.css`, I can manually change the font and font size and see the changes applied to the `<p>` element in the main window. However, the style window on the right still shows no font.

Is there some magic to showing all the applied styles?

Comment: do you have a link to the site or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Afraid not... it's a complete Joomla setup on my laptop :(

Comment: without seeing your code its impossible. Post some of it in a fiddle

Comment: have you tried IE's developer tools or chromes developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Try using another add-on for viewing your CSS code, for instance:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer

You can try other add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

A bit dumb, but probably worth answering rather than withdrawing the question...

turns out that you have to be rather more careful when selecting the html element than I'd realised. My text was actually in a span:

```
<p>
<span class="foo">bar</span>
</p>
```

The problem was simply that selecting the `<p>` element or the `bar` text doesn't show the styles applied to `bar` - you actually have to select the entire `span` element by clicking on the `span` word.

Thanks.